# XGBoost can't predict a simple sinusoidal function

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I created a very simple function to test XGBoost.

X is an array containing 1000 rows of "**7*np.pi**" for each row.
Y is simply "**1 + 0.5*np.sin(x)**"

I split the dataset in 800 training and 200 testing rows. Shuffle MUST be False to simulate future occurrences, making sure the last 200 rows are reserved to testing.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as MSE
from xgboost import XGBRegressor

N = 1000                       # 1000 rows
x = np.linspace(0, 7*np.pi, N) # Simple function
y = 1 + 0.5*np.sin(x)          # Generate simple function sin(x) as y

# Train-test split, intentionally use shuffle=False to simulate time series
X = x.reshape(-1,1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, shuffle=False)
### Interestingly, model generalizes well if shuffle=False
#X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, shuffle=False)

XGB_reg = XGBRegressor(random_state=42)
XGB_reg.fit(X_train,y_train)

# EVALUATE ON TRAIN DATA
yXGBPredicted = XGB_reg.predict(X_train)
rmse = np.sqrt(MSE(y_train, yXGBPredicted))
print("RMSE TRAIN XGB: % f" %(rmse))

# EVALUATE ON TEST DATA
yXGBPredicted = XGB_reg.predict(X_test)
# METRICAS XGB
rmse = np.sqrt(MSE(y_test, yXGBPredicted))
print("RMSE TEST XGB: % f" %(rmse))

# Predict full dataset
yXGB = XGB_reg.predict(X)

# Plot and compare
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, yXGB)
plt.ylim(0,2)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

I trained the model on the first 800 rows and then predicted the next 200 rows.

I was expecting testing data to have a great RMSE, but it did not happen.

I was surprised to see that XGBoost simple repeated the last value of the training set on all rows of the predictions (see chart).

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

[image: Test data in BLUE; Predictions in RED]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking your model to "extrapolate" - making predictions for `x` values that are greater than `x` values in the training dataset. Extrapolation works with some model types (such as linear models), but it typically does not work with decision tree models and their ensembles (such as XGBoost).

If you switch from XGBoost to LightGBM, then you can train extrapolation-capable decision tree ensembles using the "linear tree" approach:

> Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Your `XGBRegressor` is probably over-fitted (has `n_estimators = 100` and `max_depth = 6`). If you decrease those parameter values, then the red line will appear more jagged, and it will be easier for you to see it "working".

Right now, if you ask your over-fitted XGBRegressor to extrapolate, then it basically functions as a giant look-up table. When extrapolating towards +Inf, then the "closest match" is at `x = 17.5`; when extrapolating towards -Inf, then the "closest match" is at `x = 0.0`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your very clear answer! You truly helped me understand the issue and solve the problem!